# What is the proper workflow to develop and debug a NetLogo extension

Tags: java, api, netbeans, netlogo

I am developing NetLogo extensions with Netbeans, and I'd like to receive advices on the right flow in order to optimize my code... I usually write the code in NetBeans, then compile the extension within NetBeans using this add to my build.xml (I copy it here because it might be useful for someone):

```
<target name="-pre-init">
    <property name="project.name" value="myextension" />
    <property name="class.manager" value="org.nlogo.extensions.myextension.MyClassManager" />
    <manifest file="manifest.mf">
        <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0" />           
        <attribute name="Extension-Name" value="${project.name}" />
        <attribute name="Class-Manager" value="${class.manager}" />
        <attribute name="NetLogo-Extension-API-Version" value="5.0" />
    </manifest>
</target>
<target name="-post-jar">
    <delete file="manifest.mf"/>
</target>
```

at this point, I drag the .jar in the right folder, and open the NetLogo model from Terminal, in order to see if my extension writes some stuff/error/whatever... since I am no computer scientists,  I am wondering if this is the right way to proceed... I know that it works, but what if I have to see where my code is slow or memory consuming? maybe I could optimize it with a debugger, but outside NetBeans I don't know how to do it...

I'd appreciate advices on the most commonly used workflows from expert developers...

Best regards,
Simone

Comment: thank you Seth, misspelled xlm but totally missed api as a tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question. I'm curious as to how other will respond.

I create a symbolic link from the place where extension makes its jar to an appropriately named folder in the NetLogo extension folder. So, for example, if I'm working on the network extension, I'll run:

`ln -s /path/to/NW-Extension /path/to/Netlogo\ 5.0.x/extensions/nw`

This way, you don't have to go through the trouble of dragging the jar over on every build.

> I know that it works, but what if I have to see where my code is slow or memory consuming?

For profiling, I use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). I know it comes with NetBeans, but you can run it as a standalone program too. It can connect to any running JVM program. So, when testing your extension, just tell VisualVM to connect to NetLogo (though it usually shows up as "Local Application pid 42138" or something). The sampler works great for profiling.

I don't usually use a debugger when I'm working with extensions. However, you should be able to [run NetLogo from source](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Building) (use 5.0.x). I don't use NetBeans, but you should be able to point it to source code for specific jars so that NetBeans knows where to look for the source code of the classes in the jar. This should allow you to seamlessly debug the extension.

This also allows you to write [language tests](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Language-tests) for your extension. For this, you don't even need to get things hooked up with NetBeans; you can just `sbt` (which is included with NetLogo and is the easiest way to build and run it). See the wiki pages I linked to for more information.

Comment: thank you Bryan, I just wait a bit before accepting to see if others will post something... best regards

Comment: +1 on VisualVM, +1 on adding language tests to your extension (if the nature of the extension permits)